# Using memory adress from pointer to print character array (string) C

Tags: c

```
char mening[] = "tjena pa dig hog";
```

This string contains 16 characters. I am then using a function `adresss()` to find the memory address of a random character in that array. The function `adresss()` returns a pointer containing the address. The address is at this moment `0x7ffeefbff5f9`.
I now need to know what positions that address is pointing to, example is it pointing to the "t" at position 0 in the array, or maybe it is pointing to "d" at position 9. How do I do this?

Edit:

```
char* adresss(char mening[]){

   //Lots of code going on here

   return &mening[i];
}

int main(void){
   char mening[] = "tjena pa dig hog";
   char* ptr;
   ptr = adresss(mening);

   printf("%p\n", ptr);
```

That is basically how I get the memory adress. I want to know what "i" was, inside the main function only knowing the memory adress.

Comment: The adresss() function is returning like this: return &mening[i]; that will give the adress of position i in mening[] I want to find i again using only the memory adress

Comment: While the number of elements of the array `mening` is 16, remember that the last one (with index `15`) is the string terminator.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude.: The array has size `17` and index 15 is `g`.

Comment: I want to find the index of the array from the given adress

Comment: @coderredoc Details shmetails... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two pointers, both pointing to the same array (or to one beyond the end of the array), then you can subtract them from each other.

For example:

```
char mening[] = "tjena pa dig hog";
char *pointer_to_mening = &mening[10];  // Pointer to the eleventh character

// Should print 10 (which is the index of the eleventh character)
printf("The distance is %zu\n", pointer_to_mening - mening);
```

Comment: What does %zu mean?

Comment: @J.Doe `"%u"` is to print an `unsigned int`. The `z` modifier is for `size_t` arguments. That means `"%zu"` prints a `size_t` argument as an unsigned integer. See e.g. [this `printf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) for more details.